# tensorflow-gpu is not working with Blas GEMM launch failed

Tags: nvidia, tensorflow, cudnn

I installed tensorflow-gpu to run my tensorflow code on my GPU. But I can't make it run. It keeps on giving the above mentioned error. Following is my sample code followed by the error stack trace:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def check(W,X):
    return tf.matmul(W,X)


def main():
    W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2,3], stddev=0.01))
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3,2])
    check_handle = check(W,X)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
        num = sess.run(check_handle, feed_dict = 
            {X:np.reshape(np.arange(6), (3,2))})
        print(num)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My GPU is pretty good GeForce GTX 1080 Ti with 11 GB vram and there is nothing else significant running on it(just chrome) as you can see in the    nvidia-smi    :

```
Fri Aug  4 16:34:49 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 381.22                 Driver Version: 381.22                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 0000:07:00.0      On |                  N/A |
| 30%   55C    P0    79W / 250W |    711MiB / 11169MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      7650    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             380MiB |
|    0      8233    G   compiz                                         192MiB |
|    0     24226    G   ...el-token=963C169BB38ADFD67B444D57A299CE0A   136MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Following is the error stack trace:

```
2017-08-04 15:44:21.585091: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-04 15:44:21.585110: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-04 15:44:21.585114: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-04 15:44:21.585118: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-04 15:44:21.585122: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-04 15:44:21.853700: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.582
pciBusID 0000:07:00.0
Total memory: 10.91GiB
Free memory: 9.89GiB
2017-08-04 15:44:21.853724: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:961] DMA: 0 
2017-08-04 15:44:21.853728: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   Y 
2017-08-04 15:44:21.853734: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:07:00.0)
2017-08-04 15:44:24.948616: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:365] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2017-08-04 15:44:24.948640: W tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:1601] attempting to perform BLAS operation using StreamExecutor without BLAS support
2017-08-04 15:44:24.948805: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Internal: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(1, 5), b.shape=(5, 10), m=1, n=10, k=5
     [[Node: layer1/MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0/_11, layer1/weights/read)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 51, in <module>
    _, loss_out, res_out = sess.run([train_op, loss, res], feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 789, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 997, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1132, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1152, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(1, 5), b.shape=(5, 10), m=1, n=10, k=5
     [[Node: layer1/MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0/_11, layer1/weights/read)]]
     [[Node: layer2/MatMul/_17 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_158_layer2/MatMul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'layer1/MatMul', defined at:
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    pre_activation = tf.matmul(input_ph, weights)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1816, in matmul
    a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1217, in _mat_mul
    transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InternalError (see above for traceback): Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(1, 5), b.shape=(5, 10), m=1, n=10, k=5
     [[Node: layer1/MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](_arg_Placeholder_0_0/_11, layer1/weights/read)]]
     [[Node: layer2/MatMul/_17 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_158_layer2/MatMul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

To add to it, my previous installation of tensorflow cpu worked pretty well. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Note-  I have cuda-8.0 with cudnn-5.1 installed and their paths added in my bashrc profile .

Comment: upgrade your tensorflow version; also restarting the computer would help.

Comment: I did both. Didn't help

Comment: from you code it doesnt seem like you are using the latest version of tensorflow >= 1.2 .

Comment: Ohh are you saying that because of the initialize_all_varaibles ? It works in the present version too. Just gives a warning. I have the latest version installed

Comment: Did you try all the suggestions in other similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337728/tensorflow-internalerror-blas-sgemm-launch-failed and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990046/tensorflow-blas-gemm-launch-failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for me the reason for this error was that my cuda and all sub directories and files required root privileges. So tensorflow required root privileges as well to be able to use cuda. So uninstalling tensorflow and installing it again as a root user solved the problem for me.

Comment: What if you don't have root privilege?

Comment: Errrrmmmm, why not just set up CUDA so that any user can read the inlcude&lib files and execute the executables? I'd expect that to be the case by default after installation! (just checked and indeed I have it all as 755 or 644)

Answer (score 14):

I had a very similar problem. For me it coincided with an nvidia driver update. So I though it was a problem with the driver. But changing the driver had no effect. **What eventually worked for me was cleaning out the nvidia cache:**

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.nv/
```

Found this suggestion in the NVIDIA developer forum:
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1007071/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-error-when-running-matrixmulcublas-sample-ubuntu-16-04/post/5169223/

I suspect that during the driver update there where still some compiled files of the old version that were not compatible, or even that were corrupted during the process. Assumptions aside, this solved the problem for me.

Comment: Your answer saved a lot of my time. Thanks for sharing...

Comment: Thank you for your answers. For windows users, I just loaded a model to my GPU `model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50()
model.predict(np.zeros((batch_size, 224, 224, 3)))`  to remove the old cache

Answer (score 0):

Installing the right NVIDIA driver and CUDA versions for the my NVIDIA graphics card(For eg. NVIDIA RTX 2070 in my case) worked for me.