# Is there any way to run keras on GPU with tensorflow backend in many jupyter notebooks simultaneously?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

The scenario is:

1. I run keras in notebookA.
2. I run keras in notebookB.
3. I got `InternalError: Blas GEMV launch failed` when I start training my model in notebookB.

I know there is similar question here [TensorFlow: InternalError: Blas SGEMM launch failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337728/tensorflow-internalerror-blas-sgemm-launch-failed) and I can solve this by closing another notebook (notebookA) which was using the gpu).

But I'd like to know is there anyway to run keras with tensorflow backend in multiple notebooks simultaneously? Or it's no way to achieve this for now?

I tried to use the settings below in each notebook but it didn't work (got the same error).

```python
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.3
set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you tell which os you‘re on? I‘m on ubuntu and never experienced this error before even with gpu sessions in more than one notebook.

Comment: Hi, I'm using windows10 with tensorflow1.4, cuda8 and cudnn6.
So it looks like this error came from the OS...
By the way, I can run keras(tensorflow) and pytorch simultaneously without any problem.

Comment: repeatable issue on windows, azure data science virtual machine